# Build List that contains another List (Projects, Subprojects)

Tags: c#, .net, list

My data structure will be as follows:

[image]

I will be adding data with loop and there can be different amount of Sub project's for each Project.

I have created classes:

```
public class SubProject
{
    public string SubNumber { get; set; }
    public string SubPM { get; set; }
}

public class DeliveryProject
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string PM { get; set; }
    public IList<SubProject> SubNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

and then as an example tried to add data:

```
class SubnumberLevel
{

    public List<DeliveryProject> DeliveryProjectDataList = new List<DeliveryProject>();

    DeliveryProject Project = new DeliveryProject()
    {
        Number = "1234",
        PM = "John Smith",
        SubNumbers = new List<SubProject>()
        { new SubProject() {SubNumber = "1", SubPM = "John Smith"}
    }
    };

    DeliveryProjectDataList.Add(Project);

}
```

I have two questions:

1. How good is this approach of creating this kind of list taking in consideration future purpose of comparing it to another same structure list using linq
2. Currently `DeliveryProjectDataList.Add(Project);` does not compile, providing following errors:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to call the `DeliveryProjectDataList.Add` you have to call it from a function.

Answer (score 3):

Put these codes in a class's method, not in class anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have pointed out, the code you posted won't compile because the syntax isn't correct.  But the larger question of "how good is this approach.." the answer is probably that you can do better.  It may be that what you've shown is a simple POCO layer but in general you should prefer to keep your classes data private and expose only what you have too. When you don't you often end up having a lot of implementation dependencies spread through your code.

For example right now you create your objects and then set their data. This is true for all the properties from the simple fields to the list of sub projects.  If you encapsulate all that data then it makes each single class slightly more complex but simplifies the overall code and reduces the dependencies.  For example:

We make the sub projects immutable and set their data when we create them:

```
public class MFilesSubProject
{
    public MFilesSubProject(string number, string pm)
    {
        this.SubNumber = number;
        this.SubPM = pm;
    }

    public string SubNumber { get; private set; }
    public string SubPM { get; private set; }
}
```

We create the main projects with their ID values and we let them be responsible for adding sub projects.  That lets us keep the implementation of the sub project collection private. Note to keep it simple I'm giving the main project a dependency on the constructor of the sub projects.  This will be true for the mapping class as well.  If the complexity grew this might be something you'd refactor out as well.  But for now we keep it simple:

```
public class MFilesDeliveryProject
{
    List<MFilesSubProject> subprojects = new List<MFilesSubProject>();

    public MFilesDeliveryProject(string project, string pm)
    {
        this.Number = project;
        this.PM = pm;
    }

    public string Number { get; private set; }
    public string PM { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<MFilesSubProject> SubProjects { get { return this.subprojects; } }

    public void Add(string subnum, string subpm)
    {
        var sub = new MFilesSubProject(subnum, subpm);

        this.subprojects.Add(sub);
    }
}
```

Next we'll model the collection of the projects.  This might be a more substantial repository style class in your case. For the example it's just a simple wrapper around a dictionary.

```
public class ProjectSubProjectMap
{
    Dictionary<string, MFilesDeliveryProject> projects = new Dictionary<string, MFilesDeliveryProject>();

    public IEnumerable<MFilesDeliveryProject> Projects { get { return this.projects.Values; } }

    public void Add(string projectnum, string pm, string subproj, string subpm)
    {
        MFilesDeliveryProject project;

        if (!this.projects.TryGetValue(projectnum, out project))
        {
            project = new MFilesDeliveryProject(projectnum, pm);

            this.projects.Add(projectnum, project);
        }

        project.Add(subproj, subpm);
    }
}
```

Finally here's an example of how you'd use it:

```
class Program
{
    public static (string,string,string,string)[] InputData = new (string, string, string, string)[]
        {
            ( "1234", "John Smith", "1", "John Smith" ),
            ( "1234", "John Smith", "2", "John Smith" ),
            ( "1234", "John Smith", "3", "John Smith" ),
            ( "1432", "David Next", "1", "David Next" ),
            ( "1432", "David Next", "2", "David Next" ),
            ( "1432", "David Next", "3", "David Next" ),
        };

    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        ProjectSubProjectMap map = new ProjectSubProjectMap();

        foreach (var(projectNum, pm, subNum, subPm) in InputData)
        {
            map.Add(projectNum, pm, subNum, subPm);
        }

        foreach (var project in map.Projects)
        {
            foreach (var sub in project.SubProjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{project.Number}, {project.PM}, {sub.SubNumber}, {sub.SubPM}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is quite comprehensive answer! Thank you!